# triangle twice too big for mesh blueprint

Tags: procedural-generation, unreal, blueprints, unreal-5, procedural

I don't understand why the triangles covering my mesh are twice too big
[image: the actual result]

Here's my blueprints
main function calling the mesh and the triangle function:
[image: main function]

the mesh function which is supposed to work fine:
[image: mesh function]

the triangle function which produce triangle twice too big:
[image: triangle function]